# directory is not creating

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Am trying to create a directory with subfolders in my application. The new request will create folders only if the parent folder is already there but not creating if root folder is not there.

```
import { mkdir } from 'fs';

  mkdir(join(__dirname, '../folder_to_create_directory/', req.body.path), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return "error";
        }
        return "success"
    });
```

The req.body.path  is a path string eg: test/folder/subfolder. The code will work only if we create the "test" folder manually (it is not returning "success" message too even though the directory is being created). IF the test folder is not there then the directory is not creating.

expected output:-

folder_to_create_directory/test/folder/subfolder

Comment: we need to know what `mkdir` method you are using.

Comment: am using import { mkdir } from 'fs'; @flx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing an option "{recursive: true}". Try this example:

```
const { mkdir } = require("fs");
const {join} = require('path')

const path = join(__dirname, "../folder_to_create_directory", 'test/folder/subfolder')

mkdir(path, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return "error";
  }
  return "success";
});
```

Comment: yeah that was the issue, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fs` library to work with a file system.

For nested dirs:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = join(__dirname, '../folder_to_create_directory/', req.body.path);

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
}
```

Or, for individual dirs:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = join(__dirname, '../folder_to_create_directory/', req.body.path);

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
```